# How do I fix an embedded YouTube video in an iframe when it's not playing in a child window?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-api

I'm currently making a web game. Part of the game is your profile, where you can use some HTML enabled tools to make a cool character-based description. In the config menu, you can put in an audio link and, for obvious security reasons, I take that and turn it into an iframe rather than let them do that themselves.

Bla-bla-bla, you can toggle autoplaying on and off, cool- problem is, I'm experiencing some weird issues with the iframe's autoplay functionality in the first place.

See, when I hit the button to open this subwindow, it compiles the link into an iframe with an autoplay tag and everything and *even plays perfectly*, too, which is great! Buuut if I listen to it for more than ~5-10 seconds, then close & reopen the subwindow, it'll start paused. Doesn't matter if it's hidden or not. Closing & reopening immediately doesn't encounter this issue at all.

I'm making the subwindow via window.open. It's a new window each time, if that matters. Here's the code I'm using to generate the iframe:

```
function openWindow(html, charName, audio) {
    if (VS.World.getClients()[0].profile) { 
        VS.World.getClients()[0].profile.close();
    }
    var newWindow = window.open("", charName+"'s Profile", "height=600,width=900,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
    newWindow.document.write(html);
    if (audio) {
        var audioFrame = newWindow.document.createElement("iframe")
        audioFrame.width = 400
        audioFrame.height = 400
        audioFrame.id = "audioiframe"
        audioFrame.style = "display: none;"
        audioFrame.src = `${audio.replace("watch?v=","embed/")}?autoplay=1`
        audioFrame.allow = "autoplay; accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
        audioFrame.frameBorder = "0"
        var att = newWindow.document.createAttribute("allowfullscreen")
        audioFrame.setAttributeNode(att)
        newWindow.document.body.appendChild(audioFrame)
    }
    newWindow.document.title = charName+"'s Profile"
    var x = newWindow.document.getElementById("audioiframe")
    newWindow.document.body.removeChild(newWindow.document.getElementById("audioiframe"))
    newWindow.document.body.appendChild(x)
    VS.World.getClients()[0].profile = newWindow;
}
```

If it helps, everything looks exactly as expected in the subwindow. And if it's an issue- or **the** issue- making the video visible isn't possible here, though as I said earlier, doing so doesn't/didn't help the problem at hand. Or change it, even.

I tried this via document.write as well. The latter 'removeChild', 'appendChild' nonsense was just to see if I could fix it, since editing the HTML in the console and readding the iframe there works every time.

EDIT: Also worth mentioning I'm doing this all on my localhost server, haven't tried on the real deal yet.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I finally figured this out after almost twelve hours of messing with it.

Basically, YouTube's API won't let you play videos until the parent window has been interacted with. This makes sense, it's just also not listed on most of the documentation I could find since (I'm assuming here) you're almost always going to have user focus on whatever window you're trying to play a video on.

Anyway, I've no problems with complying with this and my players will probably even appreciate it since blasting music can be annoying at times.

If anyone is experiencing this in the future, my fix was simple:

1. If the user hasn't interacted with the child page yet and you try to play the video, it'll set the video's playstate to buffering (3) then to unstarted (-1).
2. So, we try to play the video when the player is loaded (under onPlayerReady).
3. In the same event function, we establish an interval (setInterval in JS, in my case) that repeatedly checks if the player's state is -1 (unstarted).
4. If it is, we try to play the video once per interval run until the child window is closed orrr-
5. Until the player's state changes to 1, in which case we know the page has been clicked, the video is playing, and we can safely clear the interval and stop caring.

Best of luck to future coders!